# Guitar Tuning in Tux Guitar - For Dummies (Drummers)

Tags: electric-guitar, tuning, tuxguitar

Can anyone help me out with Tuning in Tux Guitar? I'm a drummer and can write a rythme for guitar parts but cannot for the life of me figure out the correct way to tune to Drop C straight from Standard...

Can anyone show me the correct notational tuning within tux guitar for Drop C metal guitar tuning (like C4... B3.. that sort of thing) cus its lost on me completely...

Answer (score 2):

Drop C tuning most commonly refers to a tuning set up like this

- CGCFAD

that is,

- C3 G3 C4 F4 A4 D5

There are a few different variations on this, but this is the most widely used.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Is there any infobanks or anything on where this notation originated and why there are numbers to represent the octave? Without knowing about this notation, I'm pretty lost when it comes to tuning guitar whether physically or electronically haha

Comment: Where the notation originated, probably just "lets start on the top and go down with numbers." It's arbitrary, but pretty universal.

Comment: thanks for helpin a dumb metal guy :D